# CDK python: how to specify nat_gateway_subnets

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm using python CDK.

I can provision a VPC but the nat instances are going in the wrong subnet.
I can't figure out how to use the **nat_gateway_subnets** parameter. It seems to want a SubnetSelection -- but I can't see a way of doing that without a vpc object!?

Can anyone help? Thanks.

class Network(cdk.Stack):

```
def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, cidr_range: str, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

    self.vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, "VPC",

                       nat_gateway_subnets=??? ,
                       nat_gateways=3,

                       max_azs=3,
                       cidr=cidr_range,
                       subnet_configuration=[ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                           subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
                           name="Public-Firewall",
                           cidr_mask=25
                       ),ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                           subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
                           name="Public",
                           cidr_mask=25
                       ), ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                           subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE,
                           name="Private-Primary",
                           cidr_mask=24
                       ), ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                           subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE,
                           name="Private-Secondary",
                           cidr_mask=24
                       ), ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                           subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.ISOLATED,
                           name="Private-PrivateLink/AWS",
                           cidr_mask=25
                       ), ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                           subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.ISOLATED,
                           name="Private-TGW",
                           cidr_mask=25
                       )
                       ],
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
nat_gateway_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(subnet_group_name="Public"),
```